# file not found error when saving txt file

Tags: java, file-io, runtime-error, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I have a problem with a file saving alogrithm.

```
error:
dec 11, 2012 4:56:18 PM tetris.FileIO loadHighscores
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Koen\Dropbox\2TI\vgo\Eindwerk\Tetris\build\classes\tetris\LineHighscores.txt (De syntaxis van de bestandsnaam, mapnaam of volumenaam is onjuist)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
    at tetris.FileIO.loadHighscores(FileIO.java:44)
    at tetris.FileIO.getLineScores(FileIO.java:31)
    at tetris.FileIO.main(FileIO.java:69)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tetris.FileIO.loadHighscores(FileIO.java:49)
    at tetris.FileIO.getLineScores(FileIO.java:31)
    at tetris.FileIO.main(FileIO.java:69)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

idk what is wrong, this is a saveing algorithm for a small tetris game.

The files are saved under :

```
...\Eindwerk\Tetris\build\classes\tetris\LineHighscore.txt
...\Eindwerk\Tetris\build\classes\tetris\TimeHighscore.txt
```

I've added a main class to this class.
paste it into your ide and run it, i get many errors

```
public class FileIO   {
    private File file;
    private Scanner filescScanner, lineScanner;
    private Writer fileWriter, lineWriter;
    private String[][] data;


    public FileIO () {
        String[][] data = new String[100][1];
    }
    public String[][] getLineScores(){
        return this.loadHighscores(this.getClass().getResource("LineHighscores.txt").toString());
    }
    public String[][] getTimeScores(){
        return this.loadHighscores(this.getClass().getResource("TimeHighscores.txt").toString());
    }

    public String[][] loadHighscores(String path){
        int x=0;
        String test = "";
        file = new File(path);

        try {
            filescScanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println(file.toString());
        while((test=filescScanner.nextLine())!=null) {

            lineScanner = new Scanner(test);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter("-/-");
            System.out.println(lineScanner);
            System.out.println(lineScanner.toString());
            data[x][0]=lineScanner.next();//name    
            data[x][1]=lineScanner.next();//data   
            x++;

        }
        lineScanner.close();
        filescScanner.close();
        return data;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileIO file = new FileIO();
        System.out.println(file.getLineScores());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not passing a valid path to `new File`. `this.getClass().getResource("LineHighscores.txt")` returns a URL object. You're then getting a String representation of the URL object.

But when calling `new File(String)`, the constructor expects a path name, not a String containing a file:// URL. Since "file:\C:\Users\Koen\Dropbox\2TI\vgo\Eindwerk\Tetris\build\classes\tetris\LineHighscores.txt" is not a valid Windows path name, an exception is thrown.

There are a few ways to address this. An easy method would be to use `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getResource().toString()`. Then change

```
public String[][] loadHighscores(String path){
    int x=0;
    String test = "";
    file = new File(path);

    try {
        filescScanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

to

```
public String[][] loadHighscores(InputStream resourceStream){
    int x=0;
    String test = "";

    filescScanner = new Scanner(resourceStream);
```

This will allow you to read directly from the input files. And `loadHighScores` no longer cares whether the data is coming from an actual File, or another location. This can be handy if you ever need to read from a resource within a jar file on the classpath. You won't be able to read it directly as a file, but using getResourceAsStream can give you the content.