# PrintWriter: File not found exception?

Tags: java

```
String path=this.getClass().getResource("info.txt").toString();
void writeinfo() 
    {
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(path);
            writer.println(highscore);
        for(int i=1;i<=30;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=30;j++)
            {
                writer.println(v[i][j]);
            }
        }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        finally
        {
            writer.close();
        }       
    }
```

i just pasted the relevant part of the code. It says "java.io.FileNotFoundException", but the file does exist! I searched online but i find no solution to this.

Comment: Your working directory (where Java is looking for `info.txt`) might be different than where the code is, especially when you're running it through an IDE.

Comment: I've only just noticed you're loading it through getResource. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13829643/248065

Comment: thank you, i'll try to figure it out